# Insert via remote HTTP/SPARQL in Jena - Spring Boot 3

Tags: insert, sparql, jena, rdflib

I am looking for a way to construct a SPARQL insert query in Jena, and upload it to a remote SPARQL endpoint (served by Virtuoso's Open Edition, if it matters).
Most of the documentation references this now-deprecated pattern, which I can't seem to configure.

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT DATA { GRAPH <urn:core:services:sparql> { " +
           serializedData +
       "} }";
// Create a Virtuoso-specific UpdateRequest
UpdateRequest updateRequest = UpdateFactory.create(insertQuery);

// Create a Virtuoso-specific UpdateProcessor
UpdateProcessor updateProcessor = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(updateRequest, virtuosoUrl);
```

I have managed this in python/RDFLib by building a local graph, and extracting the triples/constructing a query and using the SPARQLWrapper, something like:

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper(virtuoso_url)
sparql.method = 'POST'
sparql.setQuery(query_start+query_body+query_end)
sparql.query()
```

What would be a/the correct way to do this in Java?
Thank you.

Comment: in recent Jena versions, using an RDF connection is the recommended way: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/#update-usage

Comment: What happens if you try? The code shown should work, even if deprecated (and going to be removed - the javadoc has the replacement if you have teh current version of Jena). It isn't a Virtuoso-specific UpdateProcessor - it's a regular standards compliant way to send updates.

What happens?

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks for that link, that clears things up quite a bit. I have gone with something like: `try ( RDFConnection conn = RDFConnection.connect(virtuosoUrl) ) {Txn.executeWrite(conn, () -> { conn.update(insertQuery);});}` which seems to work, still not sure if its the recommended way of doing things as the insertQuery is a sparql string rather than an UpdateRequest.

Comment: @AndyS thank you for confidence! Turns out I was making an error in the order of the request: insert => prefixes rather than prefixes => insert, when prepending the opening of the insert command to the stringified local Model. I ended up going with UninformedUser's answer anyway though, as it's soon to be removed.